# Laravel application hosted on apache not displaying css and javascript when accessing through browser

Tags: laravel

I have an ubuntu 20.04 hosting Laravel 9.48 application on Apache 2.4, my browser unable to render css and javascript. multiple browsers and PC accessing the server giving the same result. The Apache is tested and working fine, php is configure correctly and test with phpmyadmin. and I have another web html with css and javascript that is not developed with Laravel are tested working on the same server.

This laravel application has been updated with "composer update" to update the vendor directory, as the older vendor directory causing error when running "php artisan serve"
the updated vendor directory enable the php partisan serve command executed without error.

I have unable debug on laravel to capture any error message for troubleshooting. but there is no error being registered at all.

I have check the apache log with no error registed.

On the browser end with developer tool turned on, it receive the following errors:

````
all.min.css:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
line-awesome.min.css:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
bootstrap.min.css:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
lightcase.css:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
animate.min.css:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
nice-select.css:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
slick.css:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
main.css:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
bootstrap-fileinput.css:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
custom.css:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
color.php:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
stylesheets:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
javascript:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):56 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):56:352
jquery-3.6.0.min.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
lightcase.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
iziToast.min.css:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
logo.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
preloader-dice.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
6107c19dcf99a1627898269.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
61051300dc8531627722496.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
610515f76a27a1627723255.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
61051d8469d731627725188.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
61051a9ed28511627724446.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
61051cb37ad601627724979.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
610521608fde21627726176.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
61052482a60ed1627726978.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
610526fa315241627727610.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
61016a7a845b11627482746.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
61016c330425b1627483187.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
61016c29c44201627483177.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
61016c22d7e091627483170.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
61016c12de0c21627483154.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
6104f58044ec81627714944.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
6104f5888e32a1627714952.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
6104f58f7a1d71627714959.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
6104edb2e1eef1627712946.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
6104edad157401627712941.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
6104ed99708221627712921.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
5fa3a247df8c71604559431.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
5fa3a23fe1ad11604559423.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
5fa3a237c36d91604559415.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
5fa3a22faadaa1604559407.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
5fa3a228cc9f01604559400.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
5fa3a22252e7e1604559394.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
5fa3a21c3bc101604559388.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
5fa3a216a0be21604559382.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
6107bff04a0da1627897840.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
6107c3e6ac8fa1627898854.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
6107c4624ae9f1627898978.jpg:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
jquery.nice-select.min.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
slick.min.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
wow.min.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
app.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
iziToast.min.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(index):1139 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):1139:8
(index):1144 Uncaught ReferenceError: PhpDebugBar is not defined
    at (index):1144:19
/assets/images/logoIcon/favicon.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
stylesheets:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)```

apache access log error
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jan/2023:20:51:21 +0800] "GET /_debugbar/assets/javascript?v=1674737026 HTTP/1.1" 404 488 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jan/2023:20:51:21 +0800] "GET /_debugbar/assets/stylesheets?v=1674737026&theme=auto HTTP/1.1" 404 487 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0"
````

Comment: In which directory of the project are the css, js files located? Also please show the code you're using to  include these files.

Comment: those js and css are located under the folder `code`
/var/www/html/assets        
drwxrwxr-x 7 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 25 19:43 admin
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 25 19:43 errors
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 25 19:43 font
drwxrwxr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 25 19:43 global
drwxrwxr-x 8 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 25 19:43 images
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 25 19:43 templates`code`

Comment: what does apache log say?

Comment: @flappix the code I am using to load the css and js is blade.php located at /var/www/html/core/resources/view

Comment: @itachi i update the main to include the apache log.

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions issue.

My solution is when you have your own server running on Linux. However, even if you have access to the root via an FTP program like Filezilla or you are using CPanel, the following steps should be able to assist you in getting to the root of the problem, which is simply permissions.

Do the following

1. As a bonus, just run this command on your /storage folder. Not really directed to your issue but I want to save you future headaches

```
php artisan chmod -R 777 storage
```

This will give the correct permissions to your storage folder in case at a later stage, you will want to use file uploads etc.

Now, onto the issue

1. Usually the issue is on your .htaccess or your Apache permissions.

For Apache, you need to go to your Apache config file usually

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Check for this section

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then change this line

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

After that, restart apache. Depending on your server, on ubuntu it will be something like this

`sudo systemctl reload apache2`

Lastyl, if it is an .htaccess file issue, I usually just copy from Github, the default Laravel .htaccess file and this should usually work out of the box. Here is a [link to Laravel Github repo](https://github.com/laravel/laravel)

All the best.

Comment: Hi Charles, Thanks for your solution, I will try it out sometimes later and update on here if it works.

Comment: as for the chmod 777 command, I will try it first, but later fine tuning to 775, as it is a well known security concern, but for the sake of troubleshooting for now. /var/www/html/ is the apache root that hosted my laravel application. and in /var/www/html/folder is the subfolder that hosted my test html which consist of css and js. when i hit the browser url with localhost/folder/ it can rendered all the css and js inside the folder. so i was thinking since the subfolder is able to render css and js, hence the root directory /var/www/html/ should be correctly configure. nonetheless I will try

Comment: All the best. Definitely, chmod 775 is much better. I have encountered scenarios where the server only responds to 777, haven't figured that out myself.

Comment: sure, notify the result later, time to catch a sleep soon, been working on this whole day now. lol. thanks for your great help. cheers.

Comment: Welcome. Enjoy your rest.

Comment: thanks. good night. Cheers

Comment: I have tried your instruction, but the problem persisted. I guess this could be some issue with the laravel version which this code was initially written, isn't compatible with the latest version 9.48 that is currently running.  As I couldn't get the older laravel application running without any error, I have to run latest laravel 9.48 for my application to run without error. my thought is I need to setup the older laravel correctly which this code was written for.

Comment: I wish you all the best. You can also upgrade the Laravel gradually to the latest version or a more recent version.

Comment: I am changing the laravel version many times, but I guess there is some problem of installing multiple version on one PC. keep getting this error.   Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 8.XX when the version is older than existing version. nonetheless I am restoring my ubuntu image and try it again. thanks. will update here.

Comment: the problem has been resolved, it turn out that there is some configuration at apache2 which doesn't accept www.domainname.com as url, I have to add /index.php after the domainname before it can load all the css and js successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you had to add /index.php, that simply means you have to look more on your .htaccess configuration. That's a better way to sort that, than changing your apache configuration. However, since it works, I am glad. All the best.

Comment: thanks for your input, let me try out the .htaccess config file. it still doesn't work as we speak. will update here once i sorted it out.

Comment: `apache` `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resource|upload)` only dir ...